# Keycloak authentification not working after added intent to AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, react-native, keycloak

I'm trying to configure deeplinking with firebase dynamic link in a react native app.

We are using keycloak for authentification in our app.

If I add a new scheme to my AndroidManifest.xml, deep links work great but the authentification with keycloak no longer work (I have a black screen after loading the page, it's an authentification in browser). If I remove the new scheme, keycloak works again...

I can't understand where it comes from.

**The scheme I add for deeplinking :**

```
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="myshorturlfromfirebase.page.link"/>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.mypackagename">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:exported="true" android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="oneScheme"/>
        <data android:scheme="SecondScheme"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myshorturlfromfirebase.page.link"/> --> If I delete this line keycloak works and if I add this line deeplinking works but no longer keycloak in app authentification.

      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.batch.android.push.smallicon" android:resource="@drawable/push_icon" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.batch.android.push.color" android:value="#FF500B0F" />
    <meta-data android:name="batch_opted_out_by_default" android:value="true" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Well, as you probably guessed I would like both working, and I'm trying to figure out why keycloak authentification is no longer working in browser after adding this line.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you provide more details on what Chrome version this issue is reproducing in? Currently, there is an issue reported where the redirection is not working. Also, can you verify whether Keycloak redirects with 302 to the App Link intent? Bug link - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1303928

Comment: I just tried with firefox and I have the same issue so I don't think it's related to chrome

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that I had an "intent-filter" with two datas inside.
And after reading the docs, you need to have 2 intent filter when you want to create unique URLs, as the doc say or urls will be merged :

> Although it's possible to include multiple  elements in the same filter, it's important that you create separate filters when your intention is to declare unique URLs (such as a specific combination of scheme and host), because multiple  elements in the same intent filter are actually merged together to account for all variations of their combined attributes. For example, consider the following